# Win11 File explorer small font

Tags: windows-explorer, fonts, windows-11

I've got a new laptop and the file explorer ribbon font is smaller than everything else. Below is a screenshot, with MS Word below for comparison:

[image]

My old laptop runs the same Windows version, Version 22H2 (OS Build 22621.1992), and does not have this problem. In fact it seems to run a completely different version of the file explorer:

[image]

How can I change the font size of the file explorer only?

Comment: For starters, your old laptop runs Windows 10, not 11.

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: It seems that on the new laptop you have used a workaround to enable the *classic File Explorer ribbon menu* (which is why it looks completely different, and doesn't have the tabs etc. like the old laptop.) Would you know what you used to do that (something like a registry workaround, or ExplorerPatcher etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

There are two native ways to change the size of items on the screen:  Scale (the size of everything) and Text Size (to enlarge text size without changing Scale).

Scale is very good for High Resolution monitors.

Sometimes Scale and Text Size is a balance of what works best for you. I use both features on my Windows 11 laptops.

Individual Apps (like Explorer) cannot be natively changed by themselves - All Apps are included in text size and scale.

You can use custom sizes for Scale and Text but I find the built in sizes have the best appearance.

[image: Windows 11 Scaling]

Comment: The Text size setting does not affect the explorer ribbon font size.

Comment: That is correct and that is as I noted in my answer (individual apps cannot be changed by themselves)